# merge 2 dataframes on column when left set the value id it appears in both data frames

Tags: pandas, merge

I have 2 dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"msno":["f1", "f2", "f3", "f4"], "is_churn":[0,0,1,1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"msno":["f5", "f0", "f3", "f2"], "is_churn":[0,1,1,1]})

 is_churn msno
0         0   f1
1         0   f2
2         1   f3
3         1   f4
   is_churn msno
0         0   f5
1         1   f0
2         1   f3
3         1   f2
```

I need to merge them so all values of 'msno' will appear in the result,
and the value of is_churn will be taken from df2 if its msno appears in df1 and df2. 
The result i need looks like:

```
    is_churn  msno
0         0   f5    # only in df2
1         1   f0    # only in df2
2         1   f3    # in df2 and df1, same is_churn=1
3         1   f2    # in df2 is_churn is 1 and in df1 is_churn is 0, so result: 1
4         0   f1    # only in df1
5         1   f4    # only in df1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUIC, use

```
In [126]: pd.concat([df2, df1[~df1.msno.isin(df2.msno)]], ignore_index=True)
Out[126]:
   is_churn msno
0         0   f5
1         1   f0
2         1   f3
3         1   f2
4         0   f1
5         1   f4
```